# how to get specific value from json using ajax

Tags: json, ajax

my code is as follows

```
$.ajax({


                         url: "far-area_m.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: values,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(result){
                            //$("#res").css("display", "block");
                            var result1 = JSON.stringify(result);
                            alert(result1);
                            /*site_area = result1.site_area;
                            alert(site_area);
                            far = result1.far;
                            far_value = result1.far_value;
                            //var result = $.parseJSON(result1);

                            alert(site_area);
                            $('#site_area').val(site_area);*/
                        },
                        error:function(xhr,status,error){
                            alert(status);
                        }


                    });

    {"site_area":"54","far":"1.75","far_area":"94.5"}
```

In this i want to get site_area value. how do i get it
i have referred few links but no use. i am getting undefined as alert

Comment: can you add your **far-area_m.php**, please?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to stringify the response(JSON). If you mentioned datatype as json it automatically parse it and gives you object,

As per requirment
do as below -

```
success:function(result){
                            site_area=result.site_area;
                            alert(site_area);
                            $('#site_area').val(site_area);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

var result1 = JSON.parse(result);

site_area = result1.site_area;

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `var result1 = JSON.stringify(result);` turns your JSON object into a string, so `result1.site_area` does not mean anything. Instead try :

```
success:function(result){
    site_area = result1.site_area;
    alert(site_area);
},
```